# locale as URL parameter with ReactRouter v4 and redux

Tags: redux, internationalization, react-router-v4, react-router-redux, react-redux-i18n

I am building an multilingual application with React & Redux using :

```
{
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "redux": "3.7.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-redux-i18n": "^1.9.1"
}
```

SOLVED (using `path-to-regexp`) : https://codesandbox.io/s/307nz4p9nm

EDIT : Finally able to render components. Last trouble is the path generation, for my language selectors.

I am using a `<ConnectedRouter />` relying on `createBrowserHistory()`.

I have the following structure :

```
// containers/App.jsx
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <NavLink to={`${match.url}/`}>Home</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <NavLink to={`${match.url}/ABC`}>ABC</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <NavLink to={`${match.url}/DEF`}>DEF</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <NavLink to={`${match.url}/GHI`}>GHI</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
            <NavLink to={`${match.url}/JKL`}>JKL</NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <Router />
    </div>
    <footer>
        <Link to={ (???) }>English</Link>
        <Link to={ (???) }>French</Link>
    </footer>
</div>

// containers/Router.jsx
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={`{match.url}/`} component={Home} />
    <Route exact path={`{match.url}/abc`} component={AbcComponent} />
    <Route exact path={`{match.url}/def`} component={DefComponent} />
    <Route exact path={`{match.url}/ghi`} component={GhiComponent} />
    <Route exact path={`{match.url}/jkl`} component={JklComponent} />
</Switch>

// containers/RootContainer.jsx
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/:locale(en|fr)' component={App} />
            <Redirect to='/en' />
        </Switch>
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

Rendered this way :

```
const store = createStore(combineReducers({}))
const history = createBrowserHistory()

ReactDOM.render(
    <RootContainer store={store} history={history} />,
    document.getElementById('app-container')
)
```

Which result in the following URIs :

```
/
    /(en|fr)
        /abc
        /def
        /ghi
        /jkl
```

Now, I am looking for a way to implement my locale selectors : generate the path of the current page, just updating the `:locale` parameter.

Whatever is the route I am currently visiting (`/en`, `/en/abc`), `match.path` always return `/:locale(en|fr)` and I never access the sub-path (eg. `/abc`) from my App component.

Then how to hook `react-redux-i18n` to automatically take the locale from URL instead of managing it in its own state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Switch>` only works with Route and Redirect as direct descendents. So the `LocalizedRoute` component does not work.

```
<ConnectedRouter basename=/:locale/ history={history} />
```

The basename prop is unknown to me and unnecessary imo, remove it.

What you can do is using a dynamic route:

```
<Route path="/:locale/<path>"/>
```

And reduce on the locale param in the `LOCATION_CHANGE` action. But there are plenty more solutions, something like:

```
<Switch>
   <Route path="/en" component={SwitchMyRoutes} /> // No exact!!
   <Route path="/fr" render={(match,location)=> <SwitchMyRoutes locale="fr" match={match}/>} />
   <Route render={({location})=> <Redirect to={`/en/${location}`}/>}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Hey Dennie, thank you very much, I came to quite the similar thing, just with a parameter instead of duplicating the `<Router />` with a hardcoded locale ; However, can't find a way to generate the `<Link />` target path in a reliable way...

https://codesandbox.io/s/zrjzkjvmj4

Comment: What's the issue with that example?

Comment: The path generation part for locale selectors `<Link />` using `path-to-regexp` actually... Doesn't work as expected : navigate to `/en/topics/rendering` and click on "FR" link --> `/fr/topics/rendering` doesn't render.

Comment: Hum, actually made it work with using `path-to-regexp` and path.split('/')... It's just such a terrible way to do it IMO?!

Comment: In general, I don't like the regular expression method, I would have created static routes to `/en` and  `/fr` and simply redirect all others to `/en`.

Comment: But if your routes are static, say you are currently located at `/en/abc`, how would you create the language selector to `/fr/abc`?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wllon0wlk, your issue was with encoding of the `/` character, it rendered as unicode character, so react-router couldn't match the url.

Comment: Okay, I guess `location.pathname.substring()` works too, as long as your `/:locale` parameter always have the same length. Otherwise : https://codesandbox.io/s/307nz4p9nm